# Angular 2 Attribute Annotation does not compile

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

The following code

```
import {Attribute, Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'card'
})
@View({
  templateUrl: "app/design/card/card.html",
  styleUrls: ["app/design/card/card.css"],
  directives: []
})
export class Card {
  constructor(@Attribute('no-teaser') noTeaser) {
    this.active=false
  }
}
```

gives me the error

```
Unable to resolve signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression. Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
@Attribute('home')
```

when translating TypeScript to JavaScript.

I'm using Alpha 37, the latest definitions from DefinitelyTyped, and I'm using atom-typescript (which uses the latest typescript version)

Comment: I just copied/pasted your code and ran it through tsc and the only compilation error I hit was that the property `active` did not exist. (tsc v1.5.3). Have you tried actually compiling via tsc or are you relying on the atom plugin?

Comment: I relied in the atom plugin. Using tsc 1.5.3 it works. Is it possible to tell atom-typescript which version of tsc to use?

Answer (score 1):

> Unable to resolve signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression. Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Googling this error turn out : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3661

And in that you can see :

`Decorating function formal parameters is currently not part of the ES7 proposal.`

So I suspect `constructor(@Attribute('no-teaser') noTeaser)` is *intentionally* disallowed in the *latest* TypeScript (give `ntypescript` a go https://github.com/TypeStrong/ntypescript). Please report as an issue to Microsoft/TypeScript if that is the case.

> Is it possible to tell atom-typescript which version of tsc to use?

*Not easily* as an older version of TSC might not be *API compatible* with the latest ... but there is this option: https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/faq.md#can-i-use-a-custom-typescript-compiler

Comment: That may not the problem, because other parameter decorators such as @Host() work. Only @Attribute does not work, so this may be an angular bug? (Using TypeScript 1.5.3 everything works as expected.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with how Attribute annotation is defined in angular. I've faced the same error when tried to create my own annotation:

```
export function Attribute(name: string) {
    return function(a, b) {
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
    }
}
```

gived the same error like yours, so when I changed to this:

```
export function Attribute(name: string) {
    return function(a, b, c) {
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        console.log(c);
    }
}
```

the error is gone. Looks like you need to submit issue to angular project.

Comment: Seems like it could be related to what version of TSC you're using. 1.6 is supported but only so that the ng team can start doing builds using new TS features. The current alpha was built and tested on 1.5.3 so for now you should not be using 1.6, 1.7, etc unless you're cool getting some weird errors.